# Flutter create interest bubbles screen with dynamic sized bubbles

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know how can I develop a design like this in flutter.

[image]

I tried fixing bubbles_selection package issues and using it but this is what I got so far -

[image]

Comment: Please share a code snippet of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: you already have the algorithm of finding the position of every circle and just don't know how to position them on the layout?

Comment: @quoci I don't have any code so far and this is the UI design, not the development.
I tried multiple methods but nothing worked.

Comment: @pskink I don't have any development. This is the UI design

Comment: "I tried multiple methods but nothing worked" - so what exactly you tried?

Comment: @pskink I tried, StaggeredGridView and I got code from bubbles_selection package and fixed its errors but  didn't work (Check edited question)